# How can we replace the same value in multiple places with different values

Tags: notepad++

```
"android_pushid":["cyuuEMa12zc:APA91bE9ZttwVpHF90uEEiVdFQCB-A2JD37d_L6FFo8P-Y0CzYvzwI5YwKQw8S9wZkuWuZSzRmeGnVlcNSKDatzovPKE0x2vTZ6l9oLgkx3545EmKcTJtJHGm0VkVD3YEG_guXPrcuqO0v"],
"device_id":["8e941cb62d9792a0"],
"android_pushid":["cyuuEMa12zc:APA91bE9ZttwVpHF90uEEiVdFQCB-A2JD37d_L6FFo8P-Y0CzYvzwI5YwKQw8S9wZkuWuZSzRmeGnVlcNSKDatzovPKE0x2vTZ6l9oLgkx3545EmKcTJtJHGm0VkVD3YEG_guXPrcuqO0v"],
"device_id":["8e941cb62d9792a0"],
"android_pushid":["cyuuEMa12zc:APA91bE9ZttwVpHF90uEEiVdFQCB-A2JD37d_L6FFo8P-Y0CzYvzwI5YwKQw8S9wZkuWuZSzRmeGnVlcNSKDatzovPKE0x2vTZ6l9oLgkx3545EmKcTJtJHGm0VkVD3YEG_guXPrcuqO0v"],
"device_id":["8e941cb62d9792a0"],
```

How can i replace 8e941cb62d9792a0 with different values in each place.

Comment: Which values? What are the rules?

Answer (score 0):

You can paste those values at the end of the document and record a macro like this:

1. ctrl+end (go to the end)
2. cut the value (and remove the whole line so that the document ends at the last value)
3. ctrl+home (go to the beginning)
4. find the first occurrence of the string
5. paste the value from clipboard

Now you can repeat the makro many times to put different values from the end of a file to the next occurrence.